# combining tail -f with less +F does not work

Tags: linux, pipe, less, tail

I am using ubuntu bash. I am trying to combine tail -f and less +F like below and nothing is coming out.

```
tail -f long_running_log | less +F
```

long_running_log is a log file constantly being written by another process. The following line will show a ton of stuff on the console:
    tail -f long_running_log
But once I combine it with less +F with a pipe, nothing comes out.

In case you wonder why I am doing this, it is because I want to filter out the results of tail along the way. The real command looks like this:
    tail -f long_running_log | filter1 | filter2 | less +F

For debugging purposes, I removed filter1 and filter2 in the middle and still have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **less** man page:

```
   F      Scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is reached.  Normally  this  com-
          mand  would be used when already at the end of the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a
          file which is growing while it is being viewed.  (The behavior is similar  to  the  "tail  -f"
          command.)
```

The problem is that as long as the pipeline is still running (i.e. **tail** is still running) you won't get EOF. You can check that with a **Ctrl-C** which kills the pipeline - the filtered output is then displayed.

You can either completely drop piping to **'less +F'** (you'll get the filtered output progressively displayed in the terminal) or redirect the filtered output to another file which you can then monitor using **'less +F that_log_file'**.

Comment: Then why is it possible to do less +F long_running_log_file and show the last parts of the log file just like tail -f but with more functionalities?

Comment: Because long_running_log_file is a "real" file and thus EOF is available at any moment for the 'less +F' functionality.

Comment: You will see the same effect if you pipe to `less` (without the `+F`) and press the **End** key. Both commands suspend while seeking end of file, which isn't reached until the pipe is closed. The `p` command behaves similarly, but it does tell you what it's doing, and prompts you to interrupt.